# Is there a way to generate a BNF file from a DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd, context-free-grammar, bnf, format-conversion

I have been interested in learning to write a [JetBrains plugin](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/) for a while now and today I decided to finally give it a try. Basically I am adding language support for SVG documents because the built in XML language support can't handle tags/attributes that use the `xlink:` namespace within SVG.

So I'm working my way through the [custom language support tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html) and I've gotten to [step 3.3 - define grammar](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/grammar_and_parser.html#define-grammar). Basically I am meant to create a BNF file to define the grammar used in SVG documents. The problem is that **SVG grammar would take forever to define rigorously**.

What I would like to do is generate this BNF document automatically from the [SVG Document Type Definition](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd), because this DTD should contain enough information to completely define the grammar of SVG (I presume).

Is there any way to convert a DTD to a BNF?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/XML/2000/04schema-hacking/dtd2bnf could be a good place to start.

Comment: @bitfiddler Tried but failed. That script has no documentation on how to use it, either in the command line or in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any off-the-shelf tools; if you have any XSLT skills, it would be straightforward to use any of the various tools that translate DTDs into XML form (sometimes into XSD or RNG, sometimes just into an XML representation of the DTD structure) and then write an XSLT transformation to go into the grammar format you need for your purposes.

Allowing XML attributes to appear in any order but not to include duplicate attribute names is rather tedious in BNF; you may choose to enforce the prohibition against duplicate attribute names at a different level of your software.